# Elegant way of joining names (',' and 'and') with Ruby

Tags: ruby

If I have an array of names:

```
["Alex Ainsworth", "Bob Brown", "Charles Clarke"]
```

And I want a string where all but the last is separated with a comma (with the last being an and):

```
e.g. "Alex Ainsworth, Bob Brown and Charles Clarke"
```

Does anyone know an elegant way of doing this?

**Update: I am using Rails in this case, but I was asking a more generic question that interested me.**

Comment: Minor suggestion: it is often helpful with Ruby questions to specify if it is "pure" ruby or Ruby on Rails.

Comment: Dammit. I searched before I created the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using Rails, you could use the `to_sentence` method.

`%(alex bob charles).to_sentence` would give you `alex, bob and charles`.

That method is defined here: `activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/conversions.rb`

Comment: [Link to `to_sentence` in current code base](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/conversions.rb#L11)

Comment: `to_sentence` looks comprehensive. The support for I18n is something I hadn't even considered.

Answer (score 7):

```
[names.slice(0..-2).join(", "),names.last].join(" and ")
```